# delete elements from a data frame w.r.t columns of another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame say `df1` with MULTILEVEL INDEX:

```
       A     B     C      D
 0  0    0     1     2      3
         4     5     6      7
 1  2    8     9     10     11
    3    2     3     4      5
```

and I have another data frame with 2 common columns in `df2` also with MULTILEVEL INDEX

```
          X     B     C      Y
 0   0    0     0     7      3
     1    4     5     6      7
 1   2    8     2     3     11
     3    2     3     4      5
```

I need to remove the rows from `df1` where the values of column `B` and `C` are the same as in `df2`, so I should be getting something like this:

```
       A     B     C      D
  0  0    0     1     2      3
  0  2    8     9     10     11
```

I have tried to do this by getting the index of the common elements and then remove them via a list, but they are all messed up and are in multi-level form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a one liner using [pandas.dataframe.iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [numpy.logical_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) like this: (I find it to be the simplest way)

```
df1 = df1.iloc[np.where(np.logical_or(df1['B']!=df2['B'],df1['C']!=df2['C']))]
```

of course don't forget to:

```
import numpy as np
```

output:

```
     A  B   C   D
0 0  0  1   2   3
1 2  8  9  10  11
```

Hope this was helpful. If there are any questions or remarks please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could make MultiIndexes out of the `B` and `C` columns, and then call the index's `isin` method:

```
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1['B'],df1['C']])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2['B'],df2['C']])
mask = idx1.isin(idx2)
result = df1.loc[~mask]
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 4, 8, 2], 'B': [1, 5, 9, 3], 'C': [2, 6, 10, 4], 'D': [3, 7, 11, 5], 'P': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'Q': [0, 0, 2, 3]})
df1 = df1.set_index(list('PQ'))
df1.index.names = [None,None]


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 5, 2, 3], 'C': [7, 6, 3, 4], 'P': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'Q': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'X': [0, 4, 8, 2], 'Y': [3, 7, 11, 5]})
df2 = df2.set_index(list('PQ'))
df2.index.names = [None,None]

idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1['B'],df1['C']])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2['B'],df2['C']])
mask = idx1.isin(idx2)
result = df1.loc[~mask]
print(result)
```

yields

```
     A  B   C   D
0 0  0  1   2   3
1 2  8  9  10  11
```